# sda and sdb keep on swapping

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, uuid

The box is a HP microserver, running Ubuntu 16.04. I recently "upgraded" the boot device to a 64GB SSD. Additionally there is a 1TB SATA drive.

usually it boots up with `/dev/sda1` as the primary partition (on the SSD) and `/dev/sda5` as swap, and `/dev/sdb1` pointing to the partition on the 1Tb HDD, that is mounted to `/mnt/media0`.

The problem is, it sometimes changes all that, and the SSD is now `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb5` and the media partition is now `/dev/sda1`.

This, of course, causes the swap and media mounts to fail as they are listed in `/etc/fstab` using their previous `/dev/sd*` names.

So, I have:

1. Checked the BIOS, and it consistently lists the 64GB SSD as the first drive and the 1TB IDE as the 2nd.
2. I tried to change `/etc/fstab` to reference the media drive by volume label, but that causes Ubuntu to fail on startup and put me into a recovery mode.
3. I tried to change `/etc/fstab` to reference the swap, and (ext4) media partitions using UUID (as, in fact, it lists the primary partition) **but** I then encounter the 2nd problem I have.

When I execute the following to find the UUIDs of the various partitions...

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid
blkid
```

both only list the 1 entry – the primary partition's UUID. I can only see the UUID of the media partition using (on boots where it does, in fact, get assigned `sdb1` obviously)

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1
```

but again, if I use that UUID in `/etc/fstab` then Ubuntu fails to boot and goes into recovery mode.

So, my questions are:

- Is there any way to get `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` to stop swapping between drives?
- How can I get the system to see the UUIDs of the other partitions so I can use them in `fstab`?
- and/or is there any other way I can reliably get my swap and media partitions mounted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the "disk/by-id" names in `/etc/fstab`, see

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
```

Note that these device names may be also used in other files (initrd, grub configs). So you may update your grub config and re-recreate initrd too.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an example of how to set that fstab entry up? I've only had experience with "/dev/sd*" and "UUID=" entires in fstab.
"

Comment: You can simply replace, say "/dev/sda1" by "/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB_S2RBNXAH269511Z-part1".

Answer (score 0):

It keeps on swapping hard drive because different kernel has udev support and others have no udev (eudev) support!

Yeah, I too was bitten by this when I started experimenting with sysv, openrc and s6 init replacment (systemd replacement).

The problem lies in the grub utilities and it’s configuration files when building different Linux vmlinuz images within the same disk, ESPECIALLY when enabling `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID` (`/etc/default/grub`, et. al.) for one kernel build and not the others.

== Cause #1 ==

So … who is the culprit?  The older non-systemd.
Swapping occurs by non-systemd toward making sda drive always the starting disk label regardless of which SATA/IDE connector is used.

Drive Ordering is done by ATA (SATA or libata library) device and reordering is done by `drivers/scsi/ida_probe()`.  Remove that `GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT` from your `/etc/default/grub` file.

== Cause #2 ==

Specifying `CONFIG_SCSI_DEBUG` as “yes” (or as “m” if using initramfs with “`scsi_debug=add_host:1` in your vmlinuz bootparams) most definitely WILL push the index number of “sd” label index of your existing hard drive(s) by one:  i.e., your `sda1` becomes `sdb1`.